# NoMethodError on Mongoid method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am calling a class method of another model in my model and it seems to not find it.

**Details**

`add_existing_items` is the instance method of `Category` from where I make a call to class method of Metadata and this fails with the error.

```
Caught exception : NoMethodError : undefined method `update_or_add_metadata' for Mongoid::Relations::Metadata:Class
/Users/anil20787/workspace/repos/anil_reps/metadata_favorite/app/models/category.rb:36:in `block in add_existing_items'
```

This call to class method of `Metadata` works absolutely fine when I call it from my Category controller.

Category model:

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :catalog
  has_many :category_items

  # fields go here

  # validations go here

  def add_existing_items(inputs)
    if inputs[:category_item_ids] && inputs[:category_item_ids].kind_of?(Array)
      inputs[:category_item_ids].each do |category_item_id|
        category_item = CategoryItem.find(category_item_id)
        new_item = category_item.dup
        new_item.category = self
        new_item.save!
        # 'new_item' document gets saved successfully
        # But the below call to class method of another class fails! Why?
        Metadata.update_or_add_metadata(new_item, true)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Metadata model:

```
class Metadata
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # fields go here
  # validations go here
  belongs_to :outlet

  # instance methods go here

  class << self
    def update_or_add_metadata(item, create_new_boolean)
      # do the updating work
    end 
  end
end
```

Why am I seeing this problem? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, when you put the line `Metadata.update_or_add_metadata(new_item, true)`, it refers to the class [`Mongoid::Relations::Metadata`](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Relations/Metadata) by default, not the class `Metadata` you have defined.

Thus you need to give actual path to your `Metadata` class using scope resolution operator `::`. Then there will not be any problem. `update_or_add_metadata` singleton method defined in the singleton class of the class `Metadata` you defined, not on the singleton class of `Mongoid::Relations::Metadata` class.

Comment: Thanks. I have Object::Metadata.update_or_add_metadata call working. Is this the right way?

Comment: @bobdiya just do `::Metadata`... Enough! :-)